# Get Ether price by Unix Timestamp?

Tags: ether, etherscan, external-api, price

Is there any API I can use to get the price of Ether by providing a unix timestamp? The reason I ask is because I am using the Etherscan API to download internal transaction data but for some reason it does not include the historical Ether price, unlike when I download it using the csv export feature through the web interface. I would like to know the price of Ether at the time of each transaction, and the api provides me with a unix timestamp for each transaction.

I know how I can query the historical price by day, but what about by day and time?